# ListView signals and slots for menu elements

Tags: qt, listview, delegates, qml, qtquick2

I'm trying to implement some sort of custom Menu with custom elements. The ultimate goal is to create some sort of popup menu with text and icons. But during creation I faced with some issues. I can show 2 primary problems:

1. There is a strange menu element with title `Hello world` at the first position (looks like it's read title of application window):

[image: Hello World issue]

2. From time to time I'm getting errors like `qrc:/BreezeQuickMenu.qml:45: TypeError: Property 'clicked' of object QQuickListView(0x1120830) is not a function`

Here is my actual code:

**main.qml**

```
import QtQuick 2.2
import QtQuick.Controls 1.1
import QtQuick.Window 2.2

ApplicationWindow {
    title: qsTr("Hello World")
    width: Screen.width
    height: Screen.height
    visible: true
    id: win
    color: brPalette.normalBackground
BreezeQuickMenu{
    id: brMenu
    x: 490
    y: 199
    width: 128
    height: 256
    palette: brPalette
    menuFont.pointSize: 16
    BreezeQuickMenuItem{
        title: "Item 1"
        onClicked: mbox.show()
    }
    BreezeQuickMenuItem{
        title: "Item 2"
    }
    BreezeQuickMenuItem{
        title: "Item 3"
    }
  }
}
```

**BreezeQuickMenu.qml**

```
import QtQuick 2.4

Item {
    id: root
    property BreezeQuickPalette palette: BreezeQuickPalette
    property alias currentIndex: menuList.currentIndex
    property font menuFont
    property bool menuVisible: false
    implicitWidth: 128
    implicitHeight: menuList.height
    ListView{
        id: menuList
        anchors.fill: parent
        model: root.children
        clip: true
        delegate: Component {
            id: menuItem
            Rectangle {
                id: menuElement
                property bool isCurrentItem: ListView.isCurrentItem
                anchors {
                    left: parent.left
                    right: parent.right
                }
                color: palette.normalBackground
                height: menuText.font.pixelSize*1.2
                Text {
                    id: menuText
                    anchors.fill: parent
                    text: title
                    color: palette.normalText
                    font: menuFont
                }
                MouseArea {
                    anchors.fill: parent
                    hoverEnabled: true
                    onClicked: {
                        menuList.currentIndex = index
                        menuList.model[index].clicked()
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**BreezeQuickMenuItem.qml**

```
import QtQuick 2.4

Item {
    id: root
    property string title: "Menu Element"
    signal clicked
}
```

As you can see I'm trying to implement menu list and menu items with their own signals. I have 2 questions:

- how can I properly get rid of using title property of parent element, since I need to read title property of childrens
- what is the correct approach of using signals and slots in menu elements to avoid above error?

Please help me to understand. Full project can be pulled here:

`git clone git://git.code.sf.net/p/breezequick/code breezequick-code`

Comment: You are missing the `()` for the signal declaration, see [Signal to Signal Connect](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtqml-syntax-signals.html).  Avoid using names as similar as the built-in signals, that could generate strange bugs. It is NOT your case but it would be better to avoid potential sources of problems. 

As for the `ListView`, consider using either [`VisualItemModel`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtquick-modelviewsdata-modelview.html#visualitemmodel) or [Object Instanced as models](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtquick-modelviewsdata-modelview.html#object-instances-as-models).

Comment: Thanks, really miss this thing. Used signal name without `()` in other elements (saw this in few Qt tutorials for QML). Will fix that for others. Do you mean I can use `VisualItemModel` without delegate? But how can I create menu elements as childrens in this case? (as I show in main.qml)

Comment: Using children seems strange to me since also `ListView` itself is a child of `root`, isn't it? That sounds Awkward to me.

Comment: Understood, thanks for suggestions. Will try to use other models.

Comment: You can e.g. set the `BreezeQuickMenuItem` has children of `VisualItemModel`, or wrap them in a children `Item` and use that as a model.

Comment: Can you show me code snippet? I don't know too much yet about data models, simple example will be good beginning for me.

Comment: I'm out of office now, sorry. Maybe someone else can provide an answer with some code.

Comment: No problems, anyway thanks for your tips.

Comment: Since no answer has provided  an answer, here is my two cents. Hope it helps shedding some lights on your problems.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem with the `signal` is related to its declaration. Signals are always declared as a function would be: with a signature. In other words, a `signal` without parameters has the form

```
signal <signal_name>()
```

That's also why you got the error "`is not a function`". Apart from that, the usage of signals/signal handlers is correct. Anyhow, reading carefully the documentation wouldn't hurt. [This page](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtqml-syntax-signals.html) covers in detail the argument.

Coming to the other problem, you made the wrong assumption: anything that is declared inside a component *is* part of the `children` of the component itself. Here you declared a `BreezeQuickMenu` which has a child `ListView`. When you use it and add the `BreezeQuickMenuItem`s, you add them to the *same* set to which the `ListView` belongs. In the end you have *four* elements in the `children` property. Also, by adding the `ListView` to *itself* through the `model` you mess up things to the point that a totally unrelated string is rendered.

There are several ways to handle `Items` as model members for a view, inclusing [`VisualItemModel`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtquick-modelviewsdata-modelview.html#visualitemmodel) and using [object Instanced as models](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtquick-modelviewsdata-modelview.html#object-instances-as-models). However, by skimming your code, it is clear that you want to define a component which adds menu items in a declarative fashion. Using `children` is not sufficient in this case. You also need the `default` property:

> An object definition can have a single default property. A default property is **the property to which a value is assigned if an object is declared within another object's definition** without declaring it as a value for a particular property.

Hence you can define the `default` property for your `BreezeQuickMenu` and exploit it to obtain the desired `children` for your list. A common approach would be the following (code simplified):

```
import QtQuick 2.4

Item {
    id: root
    property BreezeQuickPalette palette: BreezeQuickPalette
    property alias currentIndex: menuList.currentIndex

    // default declaration  (1)
    default property alias contents: addItem.children

    // Item to which the inner declared meantime will belong  (2)
    Item {
        id: addItem
    }

    property font menuFont
    property bool menuVisible: false

    implicitWidth: 128
    implicitHeight: menuList.height
    ListView{
        id: menuList
        anchors.fill: parent
        model: contents                 // usage of the default property  (3)
        clip: true
        delegate: Rectangle {
            // your current delegate code
        }
    }
}
```

The basic idea is to exploit also [property `alias`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtqml-syntax-objectattributes.html#property-attributes): basically in (1) we are saying that "all the `Item`s declared inside `BreezeQuickMenu` are automatically `children` of `addItem` which is an inner declared `Item` (2). In this way the `ListView` is kept apart whereas all the `BreezeQuickMenuItem` are gathered together, under `addItem` `children` property. At this point, it is sufficient to use the same `children` property as the `model` (3) for the `ListView` and that's it.

Comment: Thanks, really great example! Didn't know about `contents` property usage, other things made this problem clear too.