# Element inheritance not working

Tags: qt, qml, qtquick2

I want to achieve some kind of inheritance, like - I have base frame, and then modify it. Here is code sample.

`BaseFrame.qml`:

```
Rectangle {
    id: base
    anchors.fill: parent

    function setButtonY (y) {
        console.log("Down to ", y)
        requestButton.y = y
    }

    Button {
        id: requestButton
        width: 200
        x: (parent.width / 2) - 100
        y: 100
    }
}
```

`DerivedFrame.qml`:

```
BaseFrame{
    anchors.fill: parent

    onVisibleChanged: {
        setButtonY(300)
    }

    Button{
        x: 100
        y: 100
        width: 200
        height: 200
        visible: true
    }
}
```

The problem is, when I use `DerivedFrame` - only `BaseFrame` is shown. If I add some buttons like below, they are never shown:

```
DerivedFrame {
    Button {
        // some stuff here + visible: true
    }
 }
```

Also - `setButtonY` correctly show log with correct `y`, but `requestButton` never move to the required `y`. Is there a way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using absolute positioning is not advised. You can exploit a positioning type (e.g. `Column`) to automatically lay out your items. However you have to ensure that, while added to `BaseFrame.qml`, `Item`s are correctly inserted in the positioning item.

When `Item`s are added to a parent, they are inserted inside the [`default`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtqml-syntax-objectattributes.html#attributes-in-object-declarations) property. In each `Item`-derived type, [`data`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-item.html#data-prop) property is the `default` one. Then we `alias` the `data` of the positioning `Item` and then make that alias the `default` property. This way we obtain the result searched in the previous paragraph. The `BaseFrame.qml` could look like this:

```
import QtQuick 2.0
import QtQuick.Controls 1.2
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.1

Item {
    id: base
    anchors.fill: parent

    default property alias hook: rowContainer.data  //aliasing 

    Column {
        id: rowContainer
        anchors.fill: parent

        Button {
            id: requestButton
            width: 300
            height: 100
            text: "1"
        }
    }
}
```

This is a `DerivedFrame.qml` possible implementation:

```
import QtQuick 2.0
import QtQuick.Controls 1.2

BaseFrame{
    anchors.fill: parent

    Button{
        anchors.right: parent.right
        width: 200
        height: 200
        text: "2"
    }
}
```

And finally here is the `main.qml` code:

```
import QtQuick 2.4
import QtQuick.Window 2.2
import QtQuick.Controls 1.2

ApplicationWindow {
    visible: true
    width: 500
    height: 500

    DerivedFrame {

        Button {
            anchors.horizontalCenter: parent.horizontalCenter
            text: "3"
        }
    }
}
```

Obviously this is just one of the possible ways to create a dynamic type. You can also have a look to [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HN9mwHWH9DU&feature=youtu.be&t=31m17s), whereas [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12772460/2538363) deals with dynamic addition. Finally [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31148671/2538363) provides another example usage of `default alias`.